# UK Kids TV Series - Mentions of "The Faculty"

Tags: story-identification, tv

In the early to mid 1980s I recall that on BBC1 (I think) there would be a series of episodes from a kids drama, lasting about 6 or 7 episodes and possibly broadcast on a Friday afternoon. There's one particular series I was taken with because it seemed so eerie and "next level" (to me, the 9 or so year old watching it).

I recall something about a "Faculty" which was doing (scientifically?) questionable things and possibly a kid (or group of kids) investigating it and coming up against the Faculty's leader/security. I recall scenes of crows being scared off whenever a specific thing happened (repeatedly) at The Faculty.

That really is all I can remember. I posted this once before, years ago on a dedicated TV series message board but got no leads. Someone help me rest my mind!

EDIT: This Faculty (We've now discovered is actually "The Icarus Foundation") were performing, manufacturing or otherwise manipulating time or human behaviour.

Comment: Was there anything fantastical or science-fictional about it that you can remember?

Comment: Yes, that this Faculty were performing, manufacturing or otherwise manipulating time or human behaviour.

Comment: @theruss You should include that detail in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a strong possibility that this was the serial called Codename Icarus.

It was a 5 part serial by the BBC on children's television and produced in 1981. You are correct in saying it had a very sinister science fiction/thriller/next level vibe.

The "faculty" you refer too was most likely "The Icarus Foundation" which in the story manipulates child geniuses for their own purpose. I dont recall the details of their plan except that it was quite conspiracy theory in style and involved nuclear war. The "time manipulation" you mention was likely a scene involving some sort of hypnosis or brainwashing of the main character.

There is a wikipedia page here...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codename_Icarus

and you can see a trailer for the show on Youtube here...

Comment: The whole series actually seems to be on youtube. Not sure if it is breaking copyright so have not posted a link but it is easy enough to find if you are looking for it.

Comment: Wicked!!! Yes it was "The Icarus Foundation" and not any Faculty! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I remember it freaked me out too. Quite fancy rewatching the whole thing now myself. Just found some more detailed info on the production of this show too...http://www.curiousbritishtelly.co.uk/2015/10/codename-icarus.html